# Cluster marker on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm not much experienced in Google Map API work but now I'm going to try it.

Currently I'm trying to create an application where user can select location type like
Restaurant, theater etc..when user will click on theater link he'll get all the theater's markers over the map around his current location and when he'll click on restaurant he'll get all the Restaurant's markers over the map along with theater's markers. I do have some lat/long details to test it.

For that I'm using Google Map API's cluster marker but now problem is that when I click on restaurant then theater marker is getting converted to restaurant marker icons.

My question is that is there any other good method to do this kind of application or I should use the same method. If yes then how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think,It's useful to You.I have tried following Api working fine.and I prepared following links.and i have used to IOS application and android.

API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=11.033538,76.958542&radius=50000&types=restaurant&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyBbFJq2_okjiRn4duMJwDCZvYoVrM_Tbtg
```

[Api used to authentication key and developing API formate](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:553488512845%3aaccess)

[Supported Type](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)